# How to use if else statement in cshtml based on id?

Tags: asp.net-core

I was trying to do an `if else` statement on my **cshtml** page. If the select value was given then the next select options should change. But how do I implement it without using *Javascript* or *JQuery*?

```html
<select class="form-control" id="SomethingHere" name="SomethingHere" onchange="show(options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
   <option value="SomethingHere">SomethingHere</option>
</select>
```

This is my first *select option* when I choose something on my first select, then on my second *select option* would change the *option list*

```html
<select class="form-control" id="SomethingHere2" name="SomethingHere2" onchange="show2(options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
   @ {
     var SomethingHere = document.getElementById('SomethingHere').val();
     //This is somehow I tried so far.
     @if(SomethingHere ==  "SomethingHere") {
        <option value="SomethingHere2">SomethingHere2</option>
     }
   }
</select>
```

Is there any other way to achieve this scenario?

Comment: You can render all the selects and keep them hidden, show the one you want based on the option selected in the first select.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible without `JavaScript` because the razor syntax only works in server-side rendering. for any update/modification you need after that, you must use `JavaScript`.

If you want to solve this problem without `JavaScript` then you should switch your front end to `Blazor` instead of `Asp.net Core`

Comment: Yea.. That's what I expect :/ ..  Just gonna go with `@Html.Raw(File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~/content/somefile.cshtml")))`  now